# DynamoDbPartitionKey annotation not picked up from implemented interface

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

I have my models defined in a kinda atypical, but neat and interesting(imo) way -

```java
public enum Product {;
    private interface Id { @DynamoDbPartitionKey String getId(); }
    private interface Cost { BigDecimal getCost(); } //this will only be provided to admin
    private interface Price { BigDecimal getPrice(); } //this would be part of public api

    @Value //lombok
    @Builder
    @DynamoDbImmutable(builder = Private.PrivateBuilder.class)
    public static class Private implements Id, Cost, Price {
        String id;
        BigDecimal cost;
        BigDecimal price;
    }
    
    @Value //lombok
    @Builder
    @DynamoDbImmutable(builder = Public.PublicBuilder.class)
    public static class Public implements Id, Price {
        String id;
        BigDecimal price;
    }
}
```

This is a manufactured example that still captures the issue I'm having.

So, the problem I'm having is that the interface `Id` needs to be implemented, in other words, there must be a method that has a return type of `String`, and is called `getId`, with no parameters. This is created by the `@Value` annotation. The problem, is that it doesn't appear the `@DynamoDbPartitionKey` annotation from the interface is being found when creating a `TableSchema` from `TableSchema.fromImmutable(name, Product.Public.class);`

I wanted to have all of the validation annotations (such as `@PositiveOrZero`) on the interfaces so that I wouldn't have to have them defined on both the `Private`(all db values) and `Public`(only values available to user) value classes. And the validation annotations on the interfaces works. But, the PartitionKey annotation looks not to be found, and a table isn't being created.

After looking at a github issue related to the annotations, I saw that the current workaround at the time was to use a `Getter` annotation on the field, and use the `onMethod` feature of lombok to also add the annotation to the generated getter, like this:

```java
    @Value //lombok
    @Builder
    @DynamoDbImmutable(builder = Public.PublicBuilder.class)
    public static class Public implements Id, Price {
        @Getter(onMethod = @__({@DynamoDbPartitionKey}))
        String id;
        BigDecimal price;
    }
```

My problem with this is that it splits the single point of control (the interface) into multiple points of control - each object that implements the interface (includes the value in the object) has annotations, and they are repeated on each one.

Is there a better way, to get the annotation from the interface to be picked up just like the `jakarta validation` annotations?

Thanks in advance.